# maximum of images (pixel to pixel) in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I've a cell containing a list of arrays which are a three dimensional images. the cell is a vector of 9 elements (the images) and I want to store in the 10th element a new image in which each pixel corresponds to the max of the corresponding pixels in all 9 elements.

Let's take an easy example:

```
I=imread('image.png');
V=zeros(size(I));
cel={I,2*I,V};
```

If `cel` wasn't a cell and it was just an array, i would compute the maximum like so easily:

`max(cel,[],3);`.

So my question is how can I do the same in case of cells without using lot of loops (maybe?)?

**EDIT**! more clarifications:

I've 9 images (above I declared only one and I created the second just by 2*I) in a cell like that `cel={I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,i6,i7,I8,i9};` and each one is an RGB image. The `I10` image will formed as the max of the 9 images, something like that: `pixel_I10(1,1,1)=max(pixel_I9(1,1,1),pixel_I8(1,1,1)...)`

I want to take the first pixel of the first image and the first pixel of the second image..etc then the max of those will correspond to the first pixel of the 10th image..

Comment: Why do you want the "max" of `imread('image.png')`, which mixes the intensities of different colors? Also, if it is "a three dimensional image", where does "a vector of 9 elements" come in? I think we usually refer to "vectors" as 1-d arrays in Matlab, do we not?

Comment: I meant by 9 elements of the cell are the images, I've 9 images stored in a cell. I edited my post for more information

Comment: Ah, now it is clear. I updated my answer. Although Ryan has already give you want. While it may seem like a loop, using `max` for element wise comparison should be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is a pixel by pixel max, I think the best way to do it is indeed a for loop. 
e.g.

```
max_image = zeros(size(cel{1}));
for i = 1:size(cel,2)
max_image = max(cel{i}, max_image);
end
```

If you really don't want to use a for loop, you could probably cast the cell to a 4d array or use a recursive function with an accumulator, but I think the loop is the simplest solution here.

Comment: Does Matlab have tail-call optimization? Up to R2014a, I am rather certain it didn't.

Comment: That's a good question, I don't actually know the answer to that. If it does, a functional solution might actually be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario with `imread` seems rather unclear. However, below is what you can use to get the max of all maximums from all the arrays in a cell named `cel`.

```
max(cellfun(@(arr)max(arr),cel));
```

In my experience (barely used anything past R2014a), `cellfun`, `arrayfun` etc are indeed faster than loops. However, there is only a constant difference in time. So the use of these functions mainly makes it easier for you to maintain your code in specific scenarios. They don't offer significant advantages in performance. Using them is *not* the same as vectorization.

**EDIT**: upon your clarifications, if you always want the elementwise max of 9 arrays, you can use `arrayfun` as follows. The earlier comment on speed and usage doesn't change.

```
arrayfun(@(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9)max(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9),cel{1},...,cel{9});
```

If your images are large and you are processing a lot of images, and say you don't always work with batches of 9 at a time, you may want to explore the use of `bsxfun`, which is highly optimized.

```
elementwiseMax=bsxfun(@max,cel{1},cel{2});
for i=3:length(cel)
   elementwiseMax=bsxfun(@max,elementwiseMax,cel{i});
end
```

`bsxfun` can still work if you need other binary functions instead of `max`. The key here is to avoid looping over all pixels, which is slow.

Lastly, you can still use `cellfun` to replace the loop if that's what you prefer.

Comment: `max(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9)` doesn't work in MATLAB. You can only take element-wise maximum of two arrays at the time.

Comment: Also, `bsxfun(@max,cel{1},cel{2})` is the same as `max(cel{1},cel{2})` if the contents of `cel` don't have singleton dimensions to expand (as is the case of images with same sizes, as I would presume the OP has).